# How can I programmatically add a field to a field group?

Tags: 8, forms

I have tried this code but it is not working.

```
$form['field_test'] = [
  '#title' => t('test'),
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => [t('A'), t('B'), t('C')],
 ];
$form['#group_children']['field_test'] = 'group_1';
```

I also tried with

```
$form['#fieldgroups']['group_1']->children[] = 'field_test';
```

But nothing is working. It works in Drupal 7. Is it changed in Drupal 8?

I have written this code in `hook_form_alter` and I'm altering a node form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re missing `'#group' => $group_id`, add that and it should work.

Like this:

```
$group_id = 'group_1';
$field_name = 'field_test';

$form[$group_id][$field_name] = [
  '#title' => t('test'),
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => [t('A'), t('B'), t('C')],
  '#group' => $group_id,
];
```

Answer (score 1):

To move an existing field (which isn't set up to show in the Manage Form Display UI) to a defined field group, all that is needed is adding #group property:

```
function ssc_custom_form_user_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['timezone']['#group'] = 'group_locale';
}
```

but don't forget the & on the $form in the function variables or the value isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put both.

```
$form['#group_children']['field_test'] = 'group_1';
$form['#fieldgroups']['group_1']->children[] = 'field_test';
```

Comment: I tried with both but not working.

Comment: Interestingly, in D9, neither of these work, alone or in combination. The only thing that does in my experiments is the accepted answer by @user72672